# Is it possible to compare DateTime and Date in SOQL

Tags: apex, soql, class

I was wondering if it is possible to compare a `DateTime` and  Date in `SOQL`.

I am trying to pull data for the product that where sold today `Date.Today()`.

`Purchase_Date__c` is a `DATETIME` field

```
Date d = Date.today();

hot = [SELECT id,Name,NRProduct__c, QuantityOrdered__c,Purchase_Date__c   
         FROM MWSOrderItem__c   
         WHERE Purchase_Date__c =:d AND Buyer_lookup__c =:UserInfo.getUserId() ];
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the solution, after a lot of research Here's [a link](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_date_functions.htm)!

code:

```
hot = [SELECT id,Name,NRProduct__c, QuantityOrdered__c,Purchase_Date__c   
          FROM MWSOrderItem__c   
          WHERE DAY_ONLY(Purchase_Date__c )=:Date.today() AND 
                Buyer_lookup__c =:UserInfo.getUserId() ];
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that will work as expected.

You will get all `MWSOrderItem__c` with `Purchase_Date__c` between 12:00am and 11:59pm from variable `d` in our case `Today`.

Comment: Hi Ray, that query should return one record but is not returning anything.

Comment: @Carlos The query is in GMT, though. Make sure you're actually on the right date.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using TODAY instead. Here is a doc on how to use it and how it works [Date Formats and Date Literals](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm)

```
hot = [SELECT id,Name,NRProduct__c, QuantityOrdered__c,Purchase_Date__c   
     FROM MWSOrderItem__c   
     WHERE Purchase_Date__c = TODAY AND Buyer_lookup__c =:UserInfo.getUserId() ];
```